# Grouping sets of data in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have been trying to separate groups in data being stored on my oracle database for more accurate analysis.

```
Current Output
Time   Location
10:00  A111
11:00  A112
12:00  S111
13:00  S234
17:00  A234
18:00  S747
19:00  A878

Desired Output
Time   Location  Group Number
10:00  A111      1
11:00  A112      1
12:00  S111      1
13:00  S234      1
17:00  A234      2
18:00  S747      2
19:00  A878      3
```

I have been trying to use over and partition by to assign the values, however I can only get into to increment all the time not only on a change. Also tried using lag but I struggled to make use of that.

I only need the value in the second column to start from 1 and increment when the first letter of field 1 changes (using substr).

This is my attempt using row_number but I am far off I think. There would be a time column in the output as well not shown above.

```
select event_time, st_location, Row_Number() over(partition by 
SUBSTR(location,1,1) order 
by event_time) 
as groupnumber from pic
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Edit:

```
Time   Location  Group Number
10:00  A-10112      1
11:00  A-10421      1
12:00  ST-10621     1
13:00  ST-23412     1
17:00  A-19112      2
18:00  ST-74712     2
19:00  A-87812      3
```

Comment: how do you specify order of these rows? is there any other column with the order? please add it to your example.

Comment: 2 columns originally, of event_time and location, with me wanting to add a third. Edited original post.

Comment: add sample data with other to columns `event_time, st_location`

Comment: I think I have done that now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a gap and island problem. Use the following code:

```
select location, 
       dense_rank() over (partition by SUBSTR(location,1,1) order by grp)
from
(
    select (row_number() over (order by time)) - 
           (row_number() over (partition by SUBSTR(location,1,1) order by time)) grp,
           location, 
           time
    from data
) t
order by time
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1a714a5bad3855bbe4bf9a0021dcafe4)

The main idea is in the subquery which isolates consecutive sequences of items (computation of `grp` column). The rest is simple once you have the `grp` column.

Comment: Just trying to get my head around how that works, as it is similar to the other answer, but I cannot seem to modify it depending on the scenario of locations.

Comment: Correction just trying it now but I believe this actually works regardless.

Comment: @JamesPavett as I said, the core of the problem is a classical gaps and islands problem (it even has a tag in SO). try to search for other questions with this tag, it may help you to understand my solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
select DENSE_RANK() over(partition by SUBSTR("location",1,1) ORDER BY SUBSTR("location",1,2)) 
as Rownumber, 
"location" from Table1;
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21120/16

Comment: That works perfectly for the first table. I have just put an edit in where I gave a second type of locations I also need to do this against. Why does it not work when there are - between the locations? Or is it because the change values (A & S) are no longer consistent in size?

Comment: @JamesPavett the solution is not correct since it does not isolate consecutive sequences ...